# Mouse "Hilighter" program for Mac OS X to use in presentations

Tags: macos, software-rec, mouse, zoom, highlighting

Is there a program that I can use as a

- **highlighter**
- **pointer**
- **zoomer**

on Mac OS X (10.6.2) during presentations?

I don't have and don't want to use hardware one.

Comment: Hightligher/poinger? Should not be _highlighter/pointer_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [OmniDazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally there is [Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/). Not free but does more than OmniDazzle. It also offers the ability to show your keystrokes on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you only asked about mouse pointer/highlighters for presentations, but another thing that is useful at the same time is keystroke highlighter or on screen display.  In fact, I found your superuser post when I was looking for just the keystroke highlighter. :-)

Anyway, I eventually found something: [KeyCaster](http://stephendeken.net/software/keycastr/)

Combined with OmniDazzle and you have a full presentation kit for highlighting your mouse and keyboard actions.

Ciao!